# How can i customize Output of My Database for my discord bot?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, discord, discord.py

[image: 1]

This is My inventory command sorry, I cant send the image cuz I don't have 10 reputations to do that,
here is my code first see the image it will help you guys get a better understanding of what I am asking pardon if it sounds rude

```
 @app_commands.command(name="inventory", description="check you inventory")
    @app_commands.guild_only()
   
   
    async def inventory(self, interaction: discord.Interaction) -> None:
        await interaction.response.defer(ephemeral=False, thinking=True)
        
        author = interaction.user.id
        lol = await self.bot.db.fetch("SELECT item_info.item_name,user_inventory.count FROM user_inventory INNER JOIN item_info USING(item_id) WHERE  user_inventory.user_id = $1",author)
        await interaction.followup.send(embed=discord.Embed(title=f"{interaction.user.name}'s Inventory ", description=f"{lol}"))
```

SO I am making a bot like dank Memer For my discord Server, I am pretty sure you guys have seen the dank memer Inventory command, How beautiful their  embed  is and the use of emoting But as I have shown you guys an image, my inventory command is kinda messy and ugly and I am getting record but I want to value and count, how can I get them and how can I make embed like dank  memer like the amount of space btw 1 item, emotes and everything I am new here so pardon if I asked something that I should not

Comment: Specify which Python library and version you are using for `self.bot.db`.

Comment: @TinNguyen i am using discord.py 2.0 and PostgreSQL 14 

`self.db = await asyncpg.create_pool(dsn = "link",ssl = "require" )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/api/index.html?highlight=fetch#asyncpg.cursor.Cursor.fetch

fetch returns a list of Record instances.

You can iterate over the list to get a single Record instance.

```
lol = await self.bot.db.fetch("SELECT item_info.item_name,user_inventory.count FROM user_inventory INNER JOIN item_info USING(item_id) WHERE  user_inventory.user_id = $1",author)

for element in lol:
   ...
```

From your image:

[image]

To the `item_name` you'd have to do:

```
element.get("item_name", "no name")
```

see: https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/api/index.html?highlight=record#asyncpg.Record
If it does not find `item_name` it will return the string `"no name"`

You created an Embed here:

```
embed=discord.Embed(title=f"{interaction.user.name}'s Inventory ", description=f"{lol}")
```

However that only has a `title` and `description`. If you want to put the `item_name` and `count` information into embed you do something like:

```
embed.add_field(name=element.get("item_name", "no name"), value=element.get("count", "NaN"))
```

see: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed.add_field

so it looks something like:

```
async def inventory(self, interaction: discord.Interaction) -> None:
    await interaction.response.defer(ephemeral=False, thinking=True)
    
    author = interaction.user.id
    lol = await self.bot.db.fetch("SELECT item_info.item_name,user_inventory.count FROM user_inventory INNER JOIN item_info USING(item_id) WHERE  user_inventory.user_id = $1",author)
    embed=discord.Embed(title=f"{interaction.user.name}'s Inventory ", description="")
    for element in lol:
        embed.add_field(name=element.get("item_name", "no name"), value=element.get("count", "NaN"))
    await interaction.followup.send(embed=embed)
```

PS: Code looks really ugly but I'm just basing mine off yours. It is not recommended but I understand you are learning.